# Android Index out of Bound error inside Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am fairly new to android & Java.

I am getting Index out of bound error for the first time.

I have looked at all the solution & tried debugging but I can't resolve it.

```
 private List<String> category = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int i = 0; i < consumerLeadsModels.get(position).getCategories().size(); i++) {
            category.add(consumerLeadsModels.get(i).getCategories().get(i).getName());
        }

        holder.quotes_categories.setTags(category);
}
```

Here I am simply adding values from a list to my String type List<> and then setting those to **Tagview**.

It is a library for displaying tags.

Cam someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Look at the exception in the Log output and tells us exactly which line the error is occurring on.  It is possible that category is not null but contains no items.  Add log output right before that holder.quots_categories line that outputs a line that displays its size Log.d("output", category.size()) and see if it is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean this?

```
category.add(consumerLeadsModels.get(position).getCategories().get(i).getName());
```

(position instead of i in the first get)